# Orchard CMS Module web.config

Tags: orchardcms

I have an existing MVC 3 web application and i'm running it as a module inside Orchard CMS.  My main web.config for the web app has a whole load of appSettings, connectionStrings, system.serviceModel and various other sections.

It looks to me as though the majority (if not all) of these settings are being ignored.

One solution would obviously be to update the Orchard.Web web.config with my settings, but i would prefer not to customise this web.config as far as possible to allow easy upgrade in future.

Are there any other recommended methods / best practices for using my own web.config within my Orchard module MVC app?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem with web.config is that it is not tenant-aware. The recommended way of treating settings in Orchard is to add parts to the Site content type. There are quite a few examples of that throughout the code.

This should give you some more info: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer here: http://blog.wouldbetheologian.com/2012/09/loading-module-specific-connection.html

```
// Read the connection string from the *local* web.config (not the root).
var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Modules/Alanta.Web.Corp/web.config");
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
_connectionString = configuration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["AlantaEntities"].ConnectionString;
```